# Centering multiple images using DIV not working in Chrome

Tags: html

I'm trying desperately to center a series of 5 animated GIFs at the bottom of a page using a DIV tag but for some reason the code that I'm using (and all other combinations I can come up with) make the images as a set slightly off-center to the right by a few pixels. The GIFs need to lined up shoulder to shoulder so that there aren't any gaps between any of them. Also I would like the images to line up perfectly with the bottom of the browser window no mater the size or resolution of the viewer's screen. The odd thing is that when I open up the same page in IE it displays perfectly. The main reason why it needs to be centered is because I'm trying to align it to a background image perfectly. I'm completely stuck, any suggestions?

Here is the code that I'm using:

> <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; text-align:center; margin-left:0px">
>   <center>5 images go here</center>
>   </div>

Answer (score 0):

IE has a tendency to treat whitespace as content in places it should not. That 2 pixels is probably a hidden space. Try collapsing whitespace in your source code. In most cases like this it's actually IE that's wrong and the problem is you aligned things in IE so other browsers appear to be wrong when in fact they are right.

To always align something at the bottom of the screen make sure your `html` and `body` tags are 100% high with no margins and padding then use position static or absolute with `bottom:0` on the elements or their wrapper.